# How to split material-ui toolbar into left and right part

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

How to split material-ui toolbar into left and right part. For example, this is my toolbar

```
let EnhancedTableToolbar = props => {
  const { numSelected, classes ,deletefunc} = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
      })}
    >
      <div className={classes.title}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
          <Typography color="inherit" variant="subtitle1">
            {numSelected} selected
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <Typography variant="h6" id="tableTitle">
            User List
          </Typography>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className={classes.actions}>
        {numSelected > 0 ? (
        <div >

        <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
          <Tooltip title="Delete">
            <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete '+numSelected +' item?')) {deletefunc()} } }>
              </DeleteIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
         <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
          <Tooltip title="Edit">
            <IconButton aria-label="Edit">
              <EditIcon>
              </EditIcon>
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
            </div>

         </div>


        ) : (
          <Tooltip title="Filter list">
            <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
              <FilterListIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        )}


      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  );
};
```

I want to show the numSelected in my left side of toolbar and the delete button and edit button at my right side of toolbar. However, my example output show the delete button and edit button just beside the numSelected. Anyone has any solution regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is add

```
flex: '0 0 auto'
```

in my actions class and a

```
<div className={classes.spacer}>
```

between title class and action class.

This is how I setup spacer, title and action classes.

```
const toolbarStyles = theme => ({
  root: {
    paddingRight: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  highlight:
    theme.palette.type === 'light'
      ? {
          color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
          backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85),
        }
      : {
          color: theme.palette.text.primary,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
        },
  spacer: {
    flex: '1 1 100%',
  },
  actions: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    flex: '0 0 auto',
  },
  title: {
    flex: '0 0 auto',
  },
});
```